# Error in grabcut function - Objective-C++ OpenCV

Tags: opencv, malloc, objective-c++

I have a problem with my grabcut algorithm written in Objective-C++ with the OpenCV library.
I want to detect balls with grabcut like you can see in this picture:

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvTQb.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
Mat imageMat;
Mat grab;
Mat result;
Mat bgdModel;
Mat fgdModel;

//x,y: user selection
NSInteger xInt = [x integerValue];
NSInteger yInt = [y integerValue];

UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);
cv::cvtColor(imageMat , grab , CV_RGBA2RGB);
cv::Rect rectangle( xInt-125,yInt-125,250,250);

cv::grabCut(grab, result, rectangle, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, cv::GC_INIT_WITH_RECT );
cv::compare(result,cv::GC_PR_FGD,result,cv::CMP_EQ);
cv::Mat foreground(grab.size(),CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
result=result&1;
grab.copyTo(foreground, result);
return MatToUIImage(grab);
```

And here is the error message I get:

```
Boule(18731,0x1b3b33b40) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1560002560) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

Do you have an idea what's wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You may be running into a memory leak. Check to see if your application's memory usage grows in task manager.

Comment: yes, but I don't understand why... This is a picture taken by my iPhone and I don't know why I'm running into a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to allocate a huge image, according to the error message.

A few things that I would do straightaway:

1. replace

   NSInteger xInt = [x integerValue];
   NSInteger yInt = [y integerValue];

with

```
int xInt = [x intValue];
int yInt = [y intValue];
```

because I am not very sure if cv::Rect() will be getting the actual inputs sent to this method.

2. Add a check to see if the origin of the rectangle is still within the image, and adjust the rectangle if it is not (grabCut seems to be fine with this, though).

I converted the code to C++, and it runs with no error after getting rid of the NSIntegers. Will update the answer after trying this on a phone, but do try the above changes.

Comment: thanks, I changed the code to explicit numbers for the rectangle and checked if it appears correctly. It does, but I'm still running in the memory leak. :-/

Comment: In that case, I will check it on iOS. Does the crash occur at the line "cv::grabCut(...), or after that?

Comment: It ja always this line cv::grabcut(...). Thank you very much!

Comment: I solved this issue by scaling down the original UIImage based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55327458/3151675